# How to add one image as a frame (border) to another image in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have some jpeg photos and need to place a frame around each of them in my WPF app. The frame is also an image, like this one:
[image: like this one]

What is the best way to do it?

Maybe it is possible to draw the image on a canvas and then draw a frame above it?

Or maybe there is a way to display the image as is and then to frame it with the border?

Comment: Use your favorite image editor to make the inner part of the frame transparent, then put two Image controls with the inner image and the frame image on top of each other, e.g. by putting both in a Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the code, that'll add the border over the photo:

P.S. It is also possible to use great [imageresizing.net](http://imageresizing.net) library and its Watermark plugin.

```
private void AddFrameAndSave(Image photo, Image frame, string outputFilePath)
{
        using (frame)
        {
            var width = 600; //Set the final image width. Usually it'll be photo.width
            var height = 450; //The same with height
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
            {
                using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    canvas.DrawImage(photo,
                        new Rectangle(0,
                            0,
                            width,
                            height),
                        new Rectangle(0,
                            0,
                            photo.Width,
                            photo.Height),
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    canvas.DrawImage(frame, new Rectangle(0,
                        0,
                        width,
                        height), new Rectangle(0,
                        0,
                        frame.Width,
                        frame.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    canvas.Save();
                }

                bitmap.Save(outputFilePath,ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make frame image as .png and make inside window transparent. WPF will render it transparent so you will not have any problem putting other image under it and that image will be displayed through transparent part of your frame image.